# How do I force laravel to use the en.json file on my translation folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I am trying to implement multi language support on laravel. I have other language like korean and spanish inside ko.jso and es.json files. BUt the problem is if I include en.json. It won't be detected by laravel. It uses the default string found in my code instead of using the value inside the en.json file. How do I force laravel to use the en.json file on my translation folder?

On my translation en.json file it has something like this.

```
{"2117-Company Information": "Company Information"}
```

on my code I did it like this:

```
__('2117-Company Information')
```

I outputed the current language that I am using, using this code

```
dd(App::getLocale()); // Output "eng"
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using?

Comment: @TravisBritz updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Is the output of App::getLocale() `eng` or `en`?

Comment: The output is "eng" not "en"

Comment: The locale should be `en` - check your `config/app.php` and see if it was changed

Comment: I check and its ``en``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all I found the issue

The first problem was my file name was "en.json" instead of "eng.json"

Second is I have number key on my eng.json file like

```
{
"1000": "test 1",
"1001": "hello world",
"1002": "awesome world",
..... 
 "2000": "test word 2000"
}
```

when I try to use the key "1000" it outputted the value for key "2000." I think it is a bug. but I replace all my keys into something like this

```
{
"1000-test 1": "test 1",
"1001-hello world": "hello world",
"1002": "awesome world",
..... 
 "2000-test word 2000": "test word 2000"
}
```

It works perfectly on my end

Comment: sorry for a late question, why you prefer to use eng instead en??

Comment: To be absolutely precise, why use `en` instead of `en_GB`?